# Cannot install php7.0-fpm via ppa:ondrej/php

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have been installing `php7.0-fpm` via `ppa:ondrej/php` on Ubuntu using the following commands without issue over the last few months whilst preparing my new server;

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

Today, I tried to install again using the same commands as above, and now I get a failure with the final command as follows;

```
root@10:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install php7.0-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-fpm'
```

Any clues as to why this install command set has suddenly stopped working?!

The same error is recorded when trying to install `php7.0-mysql`, which again was working fine until recently.

Many thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: There are plenty of other questions here which refer to the same repository, and I was really wondering if anyone else was having the same problem! I wasn't expecting quite such a negative first response!

Comment: I've tried `apt-cache search php | grep fpm`, and only php5-fpm is listed, not the php7 version. I will need to try to contact the maintainer, as all the information I can find points to the same set of instructions, which are currently not working.

Comment: It may be that my version of Ubuntu is no longer supported. I'm currently using 15.04 which appears to be now out of its supported life-cycle, so am updating to 15.10 which is current. I will post back here if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a resolution for this as shown below.

The Ubuntu version I was using was 15.04, which is now out of support.
After upgrading my install to Ubuntu 15.10 the installation of `php7.0-fpm` and `php7.0-mysql` work as expected.

It appears that the `php7.0-*` packages have been removed from the Ubuntu 15.04 version of the `ppa:ondrej/php` repo, but are available in the 15.10 version.

Currently upgrading all my servers based on this change.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The dotdeb repository seems to be working with the 7.0 extensions for me:

https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/

It's probably not ideal, but:

"Depending on your distribution (Jessie, Wheezy or Squeeze), add these two lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list file (you can also choose a mirror near you) :"

deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all

deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all

Then you should be able to install everything with:

sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv

Comment: could you please bring the necessary portion here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by necessary portion, but I added more details.